# Rake doc:app fails after upgrading to Ruby 2.1.1 and Rails 4.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rake, ruby-2.1

I use the command

```
rake doc:app
```

to generate some rudimentary documentation for my rails app. It's always worked fine in the past. Yesterday I upgraded by app from Ruby 1.9.3 to 2.1.1, and Rails 3.2 to 4.1. Everything is working fine with the app, so I went to regenerate documentation for the first time in a few weeks, and it failed. I ran the command above and got the following error message:

```
rake aborted!                                                              
Don't know how to build task 'README.rdoc'                                 
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'  
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => doc:app => doc/app/index.html                                
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I believe this is the standard error message rake delivers for a task it doesn't know. Like if I ran

```
rake foo
```

It gives the exact thing, but with 'foo' instead of 'README.rdoc'. I get the same results when I run

```
bundle exec rake doc:app
```

I'm using rake 10.2.2. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: This indicates that the file doc/README_FOR_APP is missing. During the migration the file might have gone missing. rdoc uses that as the home page, it will throw an error if that is missing

Comment: The file doc/README_FOR_APP is definitely there. I also created a blank README.rdoc file, and tried changing README_FOR_APP to README_FOR_APP.rdoc. No changes to the error message after either of these actions.

Comment: have you completed `bundle install` after changing the ruby version? then have you tried to remove `README.rdoc`?

Comment: @Малъ Скрылевъ I just removed the entire doc folder, then ran rake doc:app again, with the exact same result.

Comment: please read my questions again.

Comment: @Малъ Скрылевъ I ran bundle install before writing this question, and every time I make a relevant change, just in case. The README.rdoc file is inside the doc folder, so when I said I removed the doc folder, that implied the removal of README.rdoc.

Comment: Why `README.rdoc` have you place into the doc folder? doc folder is for compiled docs, not for source docs. Place it into the root folder of the gem.

Comment: Nope, I totally gave up, sorry! Maybe the problem will have more traction in a few months when more people have experienced it. Rake doc is really useful, so I suspect I'll be revisiting it soon. But this question is clearly going nowhere :(

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Create a README.rdoc in the **project root** folder. You might have removed it or replaced it with a README with another filetype extension.

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfectly. It's great that even old questions like this still get answered from time to time.